# From zero to parabola in 14 symbols

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Post up, weekend analytic geometers,
get ready to race for the parabola

and approach the starting **line**
with **0** and 7 other symbols:

0   =  
( *x* −1) <sup>2</sup>

And they’re off!
 
Three symbols
( +, *y*  and 2 )
assume the lead at an early **point**:

0   =  
( *x* −1) <sup>2</sup> + *y* <sup>2</sup>

Prospects don’t yet seem good for a parabola.

This is one race not meant to end in a
“winner’s **circle**.”

Whoa!
 
A cloud of dust trails an impossibly **complex** stagger through the far turn
as another two symbols
( + and 2 )
charge ahead:

0   =  
( *x* −1) <sup>2</sup> + *y* <sup>2</sup> + 2

Hold on.
 
**Two more symbols** come out of nowhere,
gain the homestretch,

and append themselves just in time.


Could it be?


Yes, at the finish line (curve, that is) it’s a *real* parabola!

> **What were those last 2 symbols?**

And how did these boldfaced puns relate to nearby equations?

       starting **line**

       early **point**

       winner’s **circle**

       impossibly **complex**

Comment: What a fun question. I know the meanings of all the puns offhand, so won't post what they mean, but still thinking about those last two symbols!

Comment: Feel free to post up the puns, @TheGreatEscaper. They would constitute a good nonsolution answer in themselves and you can always add the solution later.

Comment: This is the 400th question tagged [tag:geometry]!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An attempt at the final solution follows explanations of each <strike>bare-faced</strike> bold-faced pun in turn.

- starting **line**

  > The equation $0=(x-1)^2$ describes a line in the $(x,y)$ plane, namely the vertical line $x=1$.
- early **point**

  > The equation $0=(x-1)^2+y^2$ describes a single point in the $(x,y)$ plane, namely the point $x=1,y=0$.
- winner’s **circle**

  > Any equation of the form $0=(x-1)^2+y^2-c$ with $c$ a positive constant would describe a circle in the $(x,y)$ plane, namely with centre $(1,0)$ and radius $\sqrt{c}$.
- impossibly **complex**

  > The equation $0=(x-1)^2+y^2+2$ has no real solutions for $x$ and $y$, since squares of real numbers are non-negative and so the right-hand side should be at least $2$. So the only way to solve this equation involves treating $x$ and $y$ as complex variables.
- **real parabola**

  > We need to stick two symbols on the end of the equation $0=(x-1)^2+y^2+2$ in order to form the equation of a parabola, which in general should take the form $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ with coefficients satisfying $B^2=4AC$.

  The two last symbols (found by @TheGreatEscaper):

  > $xy$,

  thus forming the final result

  > $0=(x-1)^2+y^2+2xy$, which can be rewritten as $(x+y)^2=2x-1$ - definitely a real parabola.
  >  
  >  [image]

Comment: Doesn't appending xy after 2 work?

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper Ahhh, of course it does! Want to post that as an answer of your own? :-)

Comment: I would have voted just for "barefaced"

Comment: @randal'thor I just edited it into your answer :)

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper You're very kind :-) It was you who solved this, not me!

Comment: @humn I thought of it as soon as I saw "boldfaced" in the OP.

Comment: Very nice simplification of the finishing equation